# Definite Integral: What form is this in?

Tags: calculus

Does anyone know what form this definite integral is in?
[image: a]

It looks like it conforms to the Riemann sum below, however am confused by the first $dx/2$.  Is this typical to divide the first interval dx in half?  Thanks

[image: b]

Solution :
It appears the first $dx/2$ is the offset for the function.

Comment: the first interval is [$a$, $a+dx$]; you should take a point in that interval;  $a+\dfrac{dx}2$ is the midpoint

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have figured this out, but let me try to write it out for you.
(Also feel free to edit this answer to your liking before accepting it; in fact it would be OK for you to write your own answer and accept it, but by making this a community wiki I hope to make it easier for you. I don't get any credit for it, but that's fine.)

The sum is a Riemann sum in which 
$\Delta x_1 = \Delta x_2 = \cdots = \Delta x_n = \frac{b - a}n.$
The notation $dx$ (which I don't like, because it looks too much like the $dx$ that is usually written as part of the notation of the integral itself)
represents $\Delta x_1$ (and every other $\Delta x_k$ since they're all the same).

Therefore $a_{i-1} = a + (i-1)(dx)$ and $a_i = a + i(dx),$
and the author has chosen every $x^*_i$ according to the rule
$$ x^*_i = \frac{x_{i-1} + x_i}{2} = a + (i - 1)(dx) + \frac{dx}{2}. $$